# How do I create a straight line with evenly space points indicating a sequence of clopen sets $[a_i, b_i)$?

Tags: tikz-pgf

How do I create a straight-line figure with evenly spaced points indicating a sequence of clopen sets `$[a_i, b_i)$` in LaTeX?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Welcome to the site. As your question stands, it is not perfectly clear what you want. Please elaborate a bit on how you want the result to look like. Also, it might help if you include some try or thought about what tool you intend to use.

Comment: Ok, that fair; though, I struggle to think of a way to show that which I need to show on the page of a latex document, so I will try a better written description.

Comment: I need a horizontal line from one margin of the page to the other with evenly spaced points -the length between being arbitrary- where dots indicate the left side of the set being closed and open circles around those dots indicating the right open side.